# How to remove lines end with certain characters in python?

Tags: python, string

I have a .txt file which contains several characters in different position in lines. I want to read the .txt file and remove those lines end with ":"

The format of .txt file is:

```
Fruits&Vegetables:
Pearl 
Apple 
Orange 
Grapes: [Green] 
Cherry: [Red] 
Top 3 Anti-cancer vegetables:
Garlic 
Asparagus 
Broccoli 
Two other fruits:
Banana 
Dragon Fruit
```

I want to get this in a new dataframe

```
Fruits&Veges 
Pearl         
Apple         
Orange        
Grapes: [Green] 
Cherry: [Red] 
Garlic        
Asparagus     
Broccoli      
Banana        
Dragon Fruit
```

I have tried to use .endwith, with following code.

```
import pandas as pd
fruit = pd.Series({'Fruits&Veges':'Pearl'}
file = open('fruit.txt','r')
for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    if line.endwith(':') == -1:
       s = line
    else: s = "title"
    row = {'Fruits&Veges':s}
    fruit = fruit.append(row, ignore_index=True)
    fruit = fruit[fruit['Fruits&Veges'] != 'title']
```

I simply want to get in a new dataframe

```
Fruits&Veges
Apple
Orange
Grapes: [Green]
Cherry: [Red]
Garlic
Asparagus
Broccoli
Banana
Dragon Fruit
```

The error message is `'str' object has no attribute 'endwith'`, is there any smart way to do it quickly? Thank you.

Comment: seems to just a typo, try using `endswith`.

Comment: What do Grapes: [Green] mean in your new dataframe? is the entire thing a string?

Comment: `endswitch` returns `True` or `False`, not a number. Why are you comparing to `-1`?

Comment: It should be `if line.endswith(":"):`

Comment: How does `s = line` or `s = "title"` filter out the lines that end with `:`?

Comment: It works. I used .endswith(), Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: Please see right answer here for those who contributed to look at this. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with the following code this time...

```
import pandas as pd
fruit = pd.Series({'Fruits&Veges':'Pearl'}
file = open('fruit.txt','r')
for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    if line.endswith(':') == False:
       s = line
    else: s = "title"
    row = {'Fruits&Veges':s}
    fruit = fruit.append(row, ignore_index=True)
    fruit = fruit[fruit['Fruits&Veges'] != 'title']
```